# Total Commander on Windows 7 with Administrative Privileges

Tags: windows-7, privileges, total-commander

I'm running Total Commander on Windows 7 and I have a problem with the `Run as Administrator` issue.

If I run TC normally, it can't make changes to anything under `C:\Program Files\` without asking for permissions.

If I run TC as Administrator, Windows always darkens the screen and pops-up the warning that `An application is trying to ...`

Is there a way to avoid this warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the following article: ["How to Run Programs Elevated Without Getting the UAC Prompt"](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/run-programs-elevated-without-getting-the-uac-prompt/)

Comment: Looks promising, but doesn't work ... 
the schtasks.exe is not in the path - I found it in 3 different locations all of them seem wrong. I ran each and I always get the same error:
`ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.`

Comment: Eventually it worked great - I just had to put the Task in the 'Root' of tasks and not in the 'MyApps' folder.

Answer (score 1):

Disable UAC, that will resolve the issue with the system prompting you. To change this setting, type UAC in the search box and hit enter. Slide the slider to the bottom.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not a solution the user was asking for.

Comment: "If I run TC as Administrator, Windows always darkens the screen and pops-up the warning that An application is trying to ... 
Is there a way to avoid this warning?"  This warning is coming from UAC, and disabling UAC will suppress that warning...

Comment: I'm looking for a solution which is TC specific only. I want to be warned when a new program is about to be installed to avoid malware - but once I installed it - like TC - I don't need the 'warning' any more

Answer (score 1):

Instead of right-clicking and choosing to "Run as Administrator", right-click on the desktop icon, select Properties, go to the Compatibility tab and check the "Run as Administrator" checkbox there.